# How to build a linux kernel module against with a prebuilt kernel output directory?

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, kernel-module

My customer send me the prebuilt kernel output directory(They can not release the kernel source tree to us). This output directory is as below(under /home/michael/Clients/android_p_Hzh/kernel/kernel/):

- arch
- block
- build-in.o
- certs
- ...
- .config
- Makefile
- Module.symvers
- source (symbol link to a local source tree in my customer's file system)

Is it possible to build my external module against with this directory?

*/home/michael/Source/Linux/br_driver* is my driver's directory. I have tried to build my driver under this directory as below make command:

> make CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-poky-linux- -C
>   /home/michael/Clients/android_p_Hzh/kernel/kernel/ M=`pwd` $1

It fails with below output:

```
*** No rule to make target '/home/michael/Source/Linux/br_driver/common.o' needed by ...
```

The Makefile under *br_driver* is like below:

```
brt-objs := $(BRTOFILES)
obj-$(DRIVER_TYPE)   += brt.o

all:
    @echo "$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(CURDIR) modules"
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(CURDIR) modules

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.c *~ .*.cmd *.o.cmd .*.o.cmd \
    Module.symvers modules.order .tmp_versions modules.builtin

install:
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(KDIR) \
        SUBDIRS=$(CURDIR) modules_install
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to build kernel module against such directory. If you want us to help you with the error you got, you need to provide more information: what is directory `/home/michael/Source/Linux/` means for your machine, is `br_driver`, how your Makefile looks like and so on.

Comment: /home/michael/Source/Linux is my workspace diretory. /home/michael/Source/Linux/br_driver is the source directory of my driver. I run "make CROSS_COMPILE=..." under this directory.

Comment: Makefile looks like as below: 
...
brt-objs := $(BRTFILES)
obj-$(DRIVER_TYPE)   += brt.o

all:
    @echo "$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(CURDIR) modules"
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(CURDIR) modules

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.c *~ .*.cmd *.o.cmd .*.o.cmd \
    Module.symvers modules.order .tmp_versions modules.builtin

install:
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(KDIR) \
        SUBDIRS=$(CURDIR) modules_install

Comment: Needed **information** should be in the **question post**, not in the *comments*. (As you can see, comments are badly suited for represent multiline files and logs). Please, [edit]  you question post and add all required information into it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks you for reminding. I have edited my question.

Comment: What is content of `BRTOFILES` variable used in the Makefile? According to the error message, this variable contains `common.o` element, but you have no `common.c` file under your driver's directory. Also, I am not sure what is `$1` in your command line.

Comment: @Tsyvarev BRTOFILES := common.o ip.o custom_gpio.o. $1 is empty or **clean**.

Comment: Where do you have `common.c` file? Kbuild system expects it at `/home/michael/Source/Linux/br_driver/common.c` (near the Makefile).

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem. The only things I need is the .config and Modules.symvers. The key operation is make **oldconfig** and **modules_prepare**.